# How do I embed icons into text within Squib, the Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, squib

I added this block to my deck.rb:

```
text(str: 'Gain 1 :tribute:') do |embed|
embed.svg key: ':tribute:', file: 'tribute.svg'
end
```

However, this puts "Gain 1 [my icon here]" into the top left of every card, but not where the card text says "Gain 1 tribute."

If I add this line, in an attempt to make it specify the "Ability" column in my .csv file:

```
%w(Ability).each do |key|
```

Then I get an error message:

> "Syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end."

What do I need to add to my deck.rb, exactly, in order to make it use the `tribute.svg` icon wherever cards within the Ability column have the text, "Gain 1 tribute"?

Here's my current deck.rb:

```
require 'squib'
require 'game_icons'

Squib::Deck.new(cards: 4, layout: %w(hand.yml layout.yml)) do
  background color: '#FFFFFF'
  data = csv file: 'country.csv'
  png file: data['Art'], layout: 'Art'

  %w(Title Ability Quote Type Subtype).each do |key|
    text str: data[key], layout: key, markup: true
  end

  %w(Tribute Power Dominion).each do |key|
    svg file: "#{key.downcase}.svg", layout: "#{key}Icon"
    text str: data[key], layout: key
  end

  text(str: 'Gain 1 :tribute:', x: 275, y: 745) do |embed|
    embed.svg key: ':tribute:', file: 'tribute.svg'
  end

  save_png prefix: 'country_'
end
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The text method needs to have x and y specified. Like this:

`text(str: 'Gain 1 :tribute:', x: 300, y: 500) do |embed|
    embed.svg key: ':tribute:', file: 'tribute.svg'
  end`

As for the syntax error, every `do` needs an `end`, because you're defining a block. Although that part seems unrelated to the first part of your question. The snipped `%w(Ability).each` seems silly to me because that's just iterating over a 1-element array.

Comment: You're the best, Andy! Thank you! Won't the specified x and y mean that it puts the icon in the same place every time, as opposed to embedding it wherever the ability text happens to say "...Gain 1 tribute"?

Comment: The x and y are for the overall text string. The embed.svg figures out the x-y of the actual icon based on where `:tribute:` resides in the string (and tons of other things like how the text wraps, the font size, etc.).

Comment: Hmm, your suggestion puts "Gain 1 [my tribute icon]" into the center of every card. The "Gain 1 tribute" in the ability text is still there and hasn't been replaced, either. Am I putting your text block into the wrong place, or something? I have it as a separate block in the deck.rb.

Comment: I'm thinking there's more to your code snippet that I'm not seeing. The "ability text" you're referring to is probably a separate `text` call, so yes, since we didn't modify that call, that wouldn't change.

Comment: I've edited the OP with my deck.rb, including your suggestion. Perhaps the issue is that it's not specifying the "Ability" column in my .csv file?

Comment: Is there no way to do this? I've been trial-and-erroring with your samples for quite some time today with no luck--no matter what I do, it ends up in the top left corner on every card!